# How to assign specific colors to each datagroup in Gremlin?

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune, graph-notebook

```
%%gremlin -g Datagroup
```

Currently, I have my vertex colored and grouped via a 'datagroup' property.
Is there a way to assign specific colors to each datagroup(property) in AWS Neptune gremlin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have different colors, or even icons for the nodes, assigned. There are examples in the sample notebooks that are part of the graph-notebook project. For example if you look in the `/Neptune/02-Visualization/Grouping-and-Appearance-Customization-Gremlin` notebook, you will see this example:

```
%%graph_notebook_vis_options
{
  "groups": {
      "['CA']": {"color": "red"},
      "['MX']": {"color": "rgba(9, 104, 178, 1)"},      
      "['US']": {"color": "#00FF00"}
    }
}
```

Followed by

```
%%gremlin -p v,inv -g country
g.V().hasLabel('airport').has('code','CZM').out('route').path().by(valueMap())
```

There are additional examples in the `/Neptune/02-Visualization/Air-Routes-Gremlin` notebook.